# Node.js EventEmitter - bad things are happening

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to resolve a bug in a nodejs application, and have narrowed it down to the way I've implemented event emitters. The application is an express.js app, has uses classes. There's some critical aspect of NodeJS that I must be missing, around memory usage and class / object lifecycles. I was hoping someone could point out why what I'm doing is not working as expected.

Here's the code:

```
// ServiceWrapper.js:
var events = require('events');

var ServiceClient = function(opts) {
    this.foobar = "";
    this.opts = opts;
    this.hasFoo = false, this.hasBar = false;
}

ServiceClient.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();

ServiceClient.prototype.getFoo = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.hasFoo = true;
    self.foobar += "foo";
    self.emit('done','foo');
}

ServiceClient.prototype.getBar = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.hasBar = true;
    self.foobar += "bar";
    self.emit('done','bar');
}

var ServiceWrapper = function(){}

ServiceWrapper.prototype.getResponse = function(options, callback) {
    var servClient = new ServiceClient({});
    servClient.on('done', function(what) {
        if (servClient.hasFoo && servClient.hasBar) {
            console.log("foo && bar")
            callback(servClient.foobar);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Don't have everything: " + servClient.foobar);
        }
    });

    servClient.getFoo();
    servClient.getBar();
}

module.exports = ServiceWrapper
```

And then in my express app:

```
var ServiceWrapper = require('ServiceWrapper');

app.get('/serviceReponse', function(req,res) {
    var servWrapper = new ServiceWrapper();
    servWrapper.getResponse(function(ret) {
        res.end(ret);
    });
});
```

The behaviour on the web app works as expected: response is set to "foobar". However, looking at the logs, it looks like there's a memory leak - multiple instances of `servWrapper`. After starting the application, the first request generates:

```
Don't have everything: foo
foo && bar
```

However, if I refresh the page, I see this:

```
foo && bar
Don't have everything: foo
foo && bar
foo && bar
```

And with every refresh, the listener detects multiple 'done' events - `foo && bar` outputs keeps growing (assuming there's more and more instances of ServiceWrapper that persist in memory).

Why does this happen? (I expect to see the output that I get on the first request from every request).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the guys on #node.js on freenode for assisting with this:

> sure, but every time you attach listeners, you're attaching them to the same emitter
>   since you didn't localize the prototype's state to your instance, the prototype methods act upon the state of the prototype object.
>   I believe you can fix it by simply doing EventEmitter.call(this) in the constructor

See the following link for more info:

- http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor